# why my browser freezes when it is executing an ajax request, happening only in chrome, firefox is not showing any problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

my browser literally freezes until the ajax request is completed, why?

following is the ajax code which i am using.

```
var process;
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    if (process) return false;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * .75) {
        process = true;
        var ID = $('.more').attr('id');
        if (ID) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "localhost/ajax_more/",
                data: "last_id=" + ID,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("ul#tiles").append(html);
                    $("#more" + ID).remove();
                    $('#folPosd').fadeOut();
                    process = false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(".for_scr_l").html('No More');
        }
    }
});
```

why my browser is freezing.

Comment: It gets confused by the lack of indentation !

Comment: I am firing only one ajax request, i dont understand why it freezes

Comment: @adeneo sry i am new bee , can u plz elaborate more

Comment: He means indent your code, so it's readable and maintainable.

Comment: in call ajax synchronously(setting async=false) then browser will freeze. In the code you have given its not the case. check if you set async as global option of ajax calls. This set set using $.ajaxSetup

Comment: Do you use "process" in a busy waiting loop?

Comment: @hridayesh i am new to ajax, can u plz tell me more what u answered

Comment: @schlingel no i havent

Comment: @schlingel i have used process only to stop multiple ajax requests when the user scrolls to bottom before the last ajax is completed

Comment: I thought it should be comment so deleted answer and posted as comment. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings see the 2nd option. These options can also be set for all request using http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxSetup/

Comment: i have just noticed that its freezing only in chrome, in firefox it is not having any problems....any idea why

Comment: @user2365753 Any live example? or try to create a fiddle.